# from.emailAddress property returns an empty string in Outlook 2013 sent folder mails

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

**Setup**
- Outlook 2013 Desktop client
- Navigate to the Sent folder
- Activate the add-in

**Issue**
The [`from.emailAddress`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.1/simple-types#emailaddressdetails) property of Office JS API call returns an empty string:

```
window.Office.context.mailbox.item.from.emailAddress
```

Is this a possible bug?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a bug in Outlook 2013.

The bug has been fixed in all the latest versions of Outlook 2016.

The bug is not planned to be fixed in Outlook 2013.